# How to start executable spring boot jar file with external *.ampl on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have spring boot application with executable jar-file

So, I tried to start to from cmd in windows by command

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location="application.yaml" MyService.jar
```

and it sucessfully started

(I try to use external application.yaml to start my application)
In my application all properties.yaml like datebase mocked like this

url: ${DATA_BASE_URL}

and external yaml contains all values.

But, when I try to start application using this command on centOS (or other linux), there is fail when try to start, spring boot used ${DATA_BASE_URL} instead external application.yaml values.

How to fix it?

On linux I used

```
nohup java -jar -Dspring.config.location="application.yaml" MyService.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

you should use `double dashes`

```
nohup java -jar --spring.config.location="application.yaml" MyService.jar
```